# How to disable pylance and Jedi in Visual studio code on Linux?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm asking this because both those extensions are about to make me lose my mind. They keep returning indent errors for this line of code

```py
if_female = False:
    print(msg)
```

I literally can't indent a line, because once I do, I start getting unexpected indent errors (the 4 spaces before the print) & Syntax errors (the colon after False), and my code refuses to run.
I have Python Indent by Kevin Rose installed, and it works, but it can't get pylance or Jedi to approve of my indents.

I have tried changing my indents from Tab to Spaces, tried adding "python.jediEnabled": "False" to my settings.json file (didn't work, Jedi's still alive and kicking me in the code), tried everything Google threw at me.
I'm on a Linux machine, so please someone tell me the code to either Uninstall Jedi straight up, or fix this.

Comment: It's your syntax error, nothing to do with linters. The first line should be `if _female == False:`. Although more pythonic would be `if not _female:`

Answer (score 0):

As the comment said, this is your grammar problem.

```
if _female == False:
    print(msg)
```

In the if statement, judge by using **==**.

For the original question in the topic, you can change the following codes to your `settings.json` to disable pylance and Jedi:

```
"python.languageServer": "None",
```